# How large is this cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals, large-cardinals

The function $f(\alpha)$ outputs an uncountable ordinal from an arbitrary ordinal $\alpha$. It is defined as follows:
$$f(\alpha) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{\omega _1}\quad {\text{if}}\quad\alpha  = 0{\rm{;}}\\
{\omega _{f(\alpha  - 1)}}\quad {\rm{if }}\quad\alpha {\text{ is a successor ordinal;}}\\
{\rm{sup\{ }}f(\beta ):\beta  < \alpha {\text{\} }}\quad {\text{if }}\quad\alpha {\text{ is a limit ordinal}}{\rm{.}}
\end{array} \right.$$

Let $\gamma$ denote the cardinal such that $f(\omega_1)$ is the initial ordinal of $\gamma$. How large is $\gamma$ in the hierarchy of large cardinals? For example, how to place $\gamma$ in the hierarchy of [Cantor’s Attic](http://cantorsattic.info)?

(If $f(\alpha)$ is not well-defined for any ordinal $\alpha$, I need an explanation.)

Comment: It's not a large cardinal at all, as the term is used by set theoreticians (of which I am not one). It's less than the first uncountable weakly inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: A cardinal may be "large" as explained [here at Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/155558/what-is-the-definition-of-a-large-cardinal-axiom) or "large" as being at least in [the middle attic of Cantor’s Attic](http://cantorsattic.info/Middle_attic). It seems that $\gamma$ matches the latter definition...

Comment: OK then, I guess it's an aleph fixed point? The $\omega_1+1^\text{st}$ aleph fixed point? Did I get that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of this is defined in $\sf ZFC$, the term "large" is not very applicable here.

The function spits out $\aleph$ fixed points at all limit steps, and indeed the starting value of $\omega_1$ is irrelevant, as long as it is below the first fixed point.

So $f(\omega_1)$ is simply the $\omega_1$th fixed point, which is also the first fixed point whose cofinality is uncountable. It's not a very impressive cardinal, to be honest. It's big, sure, but most cardinals are bigger.

For example, to see that it's not very large, $V_\gamma$ is able to detect that there is a cofinal sequence of ordinals of type $\omega_1$.

---

If you want to grow faster, you can start skipping a lot more cardinals. For example:

Define $g(0)$ to be the least fixed point; $g(\alpha+1)$ is the $g(\alpha)$th $(g(\alpha))$-fixed point; limits at limit ordinals.

Here $(\alpha)$-fixed point would be defined recursively as well, $(0)$-fixed point is just any cardinal; the class of $(\alpha+1)$-fixed point is the fixed points of the enumerations of $(\alpha)$-fixed points; and for a limit ordinal $\alpha$, an $(\alpha)$-fixed point is a fixed point of all $(\beta)$-fixed points for $\beta<\alpha$.

Now $g(1)$ is so much bigger than your $\gamma$. Still, $g(\omega_1)$ is still a very small cardinal, all things considered.

(Because all of this takes place in $\sf ZFC$.)

Comment: Is it true that $f(\omega)$ is the _first_ aleph fixed point?

Comment: Yes. Note that the standard enumeration $\alpha_0=\omega; \alpha_{n+1}=\omega_{\alpha_n}$; $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_n\mid n<\omega\}$ is interleaved with $f(n)$s, so $f(\omega)=\alpha$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Perhaps I am imagining something incorrectly (since I didn't write it out in detail), but wouldn't the function $f$ (stated exactly as in OP) become constant at $f(\omega)$. To make the function strictly increasing, wouldn't we have to add a "$+1$" in the successor step definition?

Comment: @SSequence: Yes, it's a very confusing definition. You're right that $f(\omega+1)=\omega_{f(\omega)}$. So the sequence is indeed constant. (I saw that, but then managed to convince myself that it was actually okay. Not sure why.)

Comment: @lyricallywicked: See the comment by SSequence above.

Comment: I wrote this because I wanted to clarify my understanding of "fixed points", but couldn't find a clear, generalized formula. I am looking at this again, but still cannot find the problem. At the $\omega$-th step, we obtain the supremum $f(\omega)=\tau_0$. At the $(\omega+1)$-th step, we have $\alpha-1=\omega$, so we obtain the ordinal $\omega_{\tau_0}=\tau_1$. At the $(\omega+2)$-th step, we obtain the ordinal $\omega_{\tau_1}=\tau_2$. How does this function become constant?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: The problem is that $\omega_{\tau_0}=\tau_0$.

Comment: So if an ordinal $\tau$ is a fixed point, then $\omega_\tau$ is "automatically" equal to $\tau$? But then I need to clarify one detail: if an ordinal $\tau$ is a fixed point, then how large is $\omega_\tau + 1$ in comparison with $\tau$? Does $\omega_\tau + 1$ become equal to $\tau + 1$ in this case?

Comment: @lyricallywicked: That is the definition of being a fixed point. The suggestion of SSequence is to take $\omega_{f(\alpha-1)+1}$. The successor is applied to the index, not to the ordinal. (This is somewhat the implicit understanding of $+1$ when talking about cardinals, since $\kappa+1$ is not even a cardinal.) And to your last question, if $x=y$, then $x+1=y+1$ is true in any context where $+$ and $1$ are defined.